# Angular directive inside ng-repeat not two-way binding

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have a directive that simulates a simple checkbox with images:

```
movieApp.directive("imageCheckbox",
function()
{
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: { ngModel: '=' },
        template:
            '<div ng-switch on="ngModel"> \
                <div ng-switch-when="true"> \
                    <img src="/Content/Images/CheckTrue.png" ng-click="onClick()"> \
                </div> \
                <div ng-switch-default> \
                    <img src="/Content/Images/CheckFalse.png" ng-click="onClick()"> \
                </div> \
            </div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.onClick = function()
            {
                scope.ngModel = !scope.ngModel;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

This works fine outside of a `ng-repeat`. However, inside of a `ng-repeat` it won't two-way bind to the `ngModel`.

The `ng-repeat` is inside a table, something like this:

```
<tr class="movie-info-row" ng-repeat="movie in movies">
<div class="movie-checkbox">
    <image-checkbox ng-model="isSelectedToDownload" ng-click="onSelectToDownloadClick(movie.RefId)" />
</div>
```

There is a lot more inside the table row but that is not relevant here.
The `onSelectToDownloadClick` handler works and gives me the correct `movie.RefId` but the `isSelectedToDownload` flag on my scope is not updated. It is updated when outside of the `ng-repeat`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out and maybe it's useful to others as well:

The `ng-repeat` directive creates its own child scope which prototypically inherits from the parent scope.

By assigning `scope.ngModel = !scope.ngModel;` in the `onClick` function I actually create a new variable `ngModel` on the child scope, thus and thereby hiding the parent's `ngModel` variable and disabling the two-way binding.

Solution? There are a few.
I went for controller-as syntax (setting controller to `vm`) and then invoke like this:

```
<image-checkbox ng-model="vm.isSelectedToDownload" ng-click="onSelectToDownloadClick(movie.RefId)" />
```

I cannot change prototypically inherited variables themselves; however I can change their properties.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, however the controller as syntax isn't helping.  In my case the Directive sees that value as ''undefined", even though its defiantly there.  Just curious, what were some of the other options (if you recall).